# Upload App Update to Itunes Connect prior to Approval

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I submitted an app to itunes connect, and wouldn't you know it the next day found a bug.

So I fixed the bug and now have rebuilt and am trying to upload the App, but I see no way to upload a newer version of the app in itunes connect.

Attempting to just upload the archive says something along the lines of no matching app found on itunesconnect.

Attempting to create a new app on itunesconnect is not an option either, since my app signing cert is associated with the pending app... So I can't create a new entry.  Well I could but would have to create a whole new app cert etc.. which is silly.

So, can I update the exist APP prior to it being approved?  If so how? Or is my only option to delete the pending app, and recreate the entire record?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can reject the binary that you've submitted.  Note, this will reset your place in the review queue.  From the [iTunesConnect developer guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/10_ManagingYourApplications/ManagingYourApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH3-SW1) (click "Rejecting Your Binary"):

> **Rejecting Your Binary**
>
> You can reject the binary you have submitted if its status is any of
>   the following: Missing Screenshot (iOS only), Waiting for Export
>   Compliance, Waiting For Review, In Review, Pending Developer Release,
>   or Pending Apple Release. Click the Reject Binary button on the Binary
>   Details page. This action removes your binary from the review queue.
>   You can then submit another update through Application Loader after
>   you move your app back to the Waiting For Upload state in iTunes
>   Connect. If you reject your binary, your app’s status changes to
>   Developer Rejected. When you resubmit your binary, the review process
>   starts over from the beginning.

Hope this helps,

Scott H

Comment: Thanks.. I finally saw the REJECT button about 5 minutes after submitting the question.. Why they would have the button a grayed out color is beyond me, but finally did notice it. Thank you ver much.

Comment: Apple moved their documentation: This is where the information quoted above can now be found - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/10_ManagingYourApplications/ManagingYourApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH3-SW34